# Create Repository for AnkhSVN - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: repository, ankhsvn

I have just installed visual studio 2010 & also the AnkhSvn-2.3.10509
could any one help me "how to create repository for it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Links are useful to create repository

[how-to-install-tortoisesvn-and-make-your-first-repository-change](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/10/17/how-to-install-tortoisesvn-and-make-your-first-repository-change/)

[svn-intro](http://wsmoak.net/subversion/demo/svn-intro.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to create your own repository?

If you are OK with sharing your code, most hosters offer SVN repositories for free (check [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/)). If you want to keep it secret, [ProjectLocker](http://projectlocker.com/) offers free account for up to 3 projects. I'm using them for some of my private stuff and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof Kozielczyk ,
but I want to create repository on my system such that if required, I am or my friends can access it through LAN.